# does Ajax redirect to HTML is secure?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

my HTML page is querying a Servlet for login purpose and depending on servlet's result (success or failed), I redirect to the main logged HTML page directly in the Javascript function.

is it secure enough ? as Javascript is running on the client side, I'm wondering if it cannot be hacked....

Comment: Can you access the main logged in page directly, bypassing the login?

Comment: yes, but I intend to create a cookie in the login page if it is successful and then check for it in the main page....

Comment: or may be it is better to create the cookie on the Servlet side and send it back as a response to the Javascript who will redirect to the main page ?